# Enabling multiple team admins to build an app for distribution in XCode 4.3?

Tags: ios, app-store, distribution, app-store-connect

Please excuse the terminology if it's wrong. The use case is simple. 
There is only one team agent who can release an app to the general public.
How can we let team admins have the same permission?

I can't find the pic for the life of me, but there was a comparison chart in the Apple Provision Profile that indicated that the only "powers" that a team agent had over a team admin was being the point of legal contact.  So I got the idea that team admins can in fact distribute an app?

I'm not sure all that's involved, but this post is 2 years old, and I was hoping that someone had an updated set of instructions:  [iPhone: Can a dev other than team agent build an app for distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629057/iphone-can-a-dev-other-than-team-agent-build-an-app-for-distribution)

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking if theres a way to make a second agent account to download provisioning profiles with, or a way to submit apps to the App Store from multiple computers?

Comment: Yes, a second developer (agent) on our dev team who has permissions set to get our app into the app store (by making a distribution profiles I gather). In other words, 2 team agents. This has got to be a common scenario.

Comment: I have exactly the same question, any answer yet?  The only thing I can come up with is to share the private team key...